# In the below code, unable to set the value in datapicker using onchange event and name attribute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

````
```
const initialValues = {
    code: '',
    product: '',
    checked: 'false',
    jobCardNo: '',
    openDate: '',
    completionDate: '',
    serial: '',
    technicalNo: '',
    lineNo: '',
    show: false,
  };
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleInput = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any } }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```
````

```
const initialValues = {
    code: '',
    product: '',
    checked: 'false',
    jobCardNo: '',
    openDate: '',
    completionDate: '',
    serial: '',
    technicalNo: '',
    lineNo: '',
    show: false,
  };
  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

  const handleInput = (e: { target: { name: any; value: any } }) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };
```

I am using the above object for handling the input fields, when coming to the Material UI date picker unable to do it. The name attribute doesnt exist in date picker. Any solution for this.Thanks in Advance

```
<DatePicker
 value={props.openDate}
 onChange={props.handleInput}
 renderInput={(params) => (
 <TextField name="openDate" {...params} />
 )}
 />
```

Comment: You never use `values.openDate`, you are always using `props.openDate`

Comment: Yes the initialValues defined in the parent component and the datePicker is in child component. So sending the values as a props and using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MUI DatePicker's [onChange](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#props) function returns the first argument as the new value.

So, in your `DatePicker` you need to replace:

```
onChange={props.handleInput}
```

with this line:

```
onChange={(newValue) => props.handleInput({target: {name:"openDate", value: newValue}})}
```

in order to handle `DatePicker` with the same handleInput function with the `TextField`.